# Was this edit completely inappropriate

Tags: discussion

On [this answer to a poorly written question (that I tried to improve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138962/cannot-resolve-symbol-fragment),  [an edit was made](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30138982/revisions) that clearly conflicts with the original answerers intent, but improves the answer...

So should I rollback the edit, or add a comment directed to the editor asking for it to be put in a comment?

Comment: also, the edit appears to have been approved...

Comment: It was approved by the author of the answer.  There is nothing to do.  I would have rejected it myself but the author's vote supercedes any of the reviewers (assuming the author reviews it before the edit is approved or rejected)

Comment: yeah I guess as it improves the answer, and meets with the approval of the original author it's an occasion where what we would reject as reviewers gets approved anyway!

Comment: That editor is `code tick` addicted and leaves major issues unchanged. I left him a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a potential reviewer, I would have rejected the edit as it does not conform to the communities accepted guidelines on editing.  It attempted to add information to the post that was not part of the original answer.

But once it gets approved is where it gets messy.

If it is approved by the answer's author (as was the case here), then there is nothing more to do.  The author's wishes normally should supersede anything else.  Rolling back in this case should only be done for extremely bad edits that make the post significantly worse.

But if it is approved by 3 reviewers and not the answers author, then the problem with rolling back comes up.

I don't think you should automatically roll it back, because the edit may have added valuable info (just done incorrectly).  If you are absolutely certain the edited in info is not correct, then roll it back, but if you aren't sure or if it is correct, then just leave it alone.